Range coder with simple adaptive frequency model
Range coder implementation provided here is not the same as the traditional arithmetic coder covered by historical patents. Range coding was developed as a patent-free alternative to arithmetic coding. Implemented by the book. Performance and memory footprint - no goals. Simplicity is.
Range coder with simple adaptive frequency model.
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

// https://gist.github.com/leok7v/9e09be9319a77a3d7e2da4d780d9905f

enum { // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_coding
    range_coder_bits    = 15,
    range_coder_sym_max = 1u << range_coder_bits,
};

struct range_coder {
    // state:
    uint64_t low;
    uint64_t range;
    uint64_t code;
    // adaptive model:
    uint64_t freq[range_coder_sym_max]; // Symbol frequencies
    uint64_t tree[range_coder_sym_max + 1]; // Fenwick Tree (1-based indexing)
    uint64_t total; // sum of all freq
    // stream:
    void* stream;
    errno_t  (*write)(struct range_coder* rc, uint8_t b);
    errno_t  (*read)(struct range_coder* rc, uint8_t* b);
};

static void rc_ft_init(uint64_t* tree, size_t size) { // Fenwick Tree
    memset(tree, 0, sizeof(uint64_t) * size);
}

static void rc_ft_update(uint64_t* tree, size_t size, uint32_t i, int64_t v) {
    // Update Fenwick Tree at position index 'i' by value 'v'
    i++;  // Convert to 1-based i
    while (i < size) {
        tree[i] += v;
        i += i & (~i + 1);  // Extract least significant set bit
    }
}

static uint64_t rc_ft_query(uint64_t* tree, uint32_t i) {
    uint64_t sum = 0; // cumulative frequency up to and including 'i'
    i++;  // Convert to 1-based i
    while (i > 0) {
        sum += tree[i];
        i -= i & (~i + 1);  // Extract least significant set bit
    }
    return sum;
}

static void rc_am_update(struct range_coder* rc, uint16_t symbol) {
    // Update the rc after encoding/decoding a s
    if (rc->total >= INT64_MAX / 2) {
        // Rescale freq to prevent overflow
        rc->total = 0;
        rc_ft_init(rc->tree, range_coder_sym_max + 1);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < range_coder_sym_max; i++) {
            rc->freq[i] = (rc->freq[i] + 1) / 2;
            rc_ft_update(rc->tree, range_coder_sym_max + 1, i, rc->freq[i]);
            rc->total += rc->freq[i];
        }
    }
    rc->freq[symbol]++;
    rc_ft_update(rc->tree, range_coder_sym_max + 1, symbol, 1);
    rc->total++;
}

static void rc_init_am(struct range_coder* rc) { // init adaptive model
    rc->total = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < range_coder_sym_max; i++) {
        rc->freq[i] = 1;
    }
    rc_ft_init(rc->tree, range_coder_sym_max + 1);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < range_coder_sym_max; i++) {
        rc_ft_update(rc->tree, range_coder_sym_max + 1, i, rc->freq[i]);
        rc->total += rc->freq[i];
    }
}

static void rc_init_encoder(struct range_coder* rc) {
    rc->code = 0;
    rc->low = 0;
    rc->range = UINT64_MAX;
    rc_init_am(rc);
}

static errno_t rc_init_decoder(struct range_coder* rc) {
    uint64_t code = 0; // first 8 bytes
    errno_t r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8 && r == 0; i++) {
        uint8_t b = 0;
        r = rc->read(rc, &b);
        code = (code << 8) | b;
    }
    if (r == 0) {
        rc->code = code; // first 64 bits from input stream as is
        rc->low = 0;
        rc->range = UINT64_MAX;
        rc_init_am(rc);
    }
    return r;
}

#define range_coder_top    (1uLL << (range_coder_bits * 3 - 1))
#define range_coder_bottom (1uLL << (range_coder_bits * 3 - 5))

errno_t rc_encode(struct range_coder* rc, uint16_t symbol) {
    uint64_t total = rc->total;
    uint64_t cum_freq = symbol > 0 ? rc_ft_query(rc->tree, symbol - 1) : 0;
    uint64_t freq = rc->freq[symbol];
    uint64_t r = rc->range / total;
    rc->low += r * cum_freq;
    rc->range = r * freq;
    while (1) {
        if ((rc->low ^ (rc->low + rc->range)) < range_coder_top) {
            errno_t r = rc->write(rc, rc->low >> (64 - 8));
            if (r != 0) { return r; }
            rc->range <<= 8;
            rc->low <<= 8;
        } else if (rc->range < range_coder_bottom) {
            rc->range <<= 8;
            rc->low <<= 8;
            errno_t r = rc->write(rc, rc->low >> (64 - 8));
            if (r != 0) { return r; }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    rc_am_update(rc, symbol);
    return 0;
}

errno_t rc_flush(struct range_coder* rc) { // finish encode
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        errno_t r = rc->write(rc, rc->low >> (64 - 8));
        if (r != 0) { return r; }
        rc->low <<= 8;
    }
    return 0;
}

errno_t rc_decode(struct range_coder* rc, uint16_t* symbol) {
    uint64_t total = rc->total;
    uint64_t r = rc->range / total;
    uint64_t count = (rc->code - rc->low) / r;
    // Binary search to find the s
    uint16_t s = 0;
    uint32_t low = 0, high = range_coder_sym_max - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        uint32_t mid = (low + high) / 2;
        uint64_t cum_freq = rc_ft_query(rc->tree, mid);
        if (cum_freq <= count) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    s = low;
    uint64_t cum_freq_symbol = s > 0 ? rc_ft_query(rc->tree, s - 1) : 0;
    uint64_t freq = rc->freq[s];
    rc->low += r * cum_freq_symbol;
    rc->range = r * freq;
    while (1) {
        if ((rc->low ^ (rc->low + rc->range)) < range_coder_top) {
            rc->range <<= 8;
            rc->low <<= 8;
            uint8_t c = 0;
            errno_t r = rc->read(rc, &c);
            if (r != 0) { return r; }
            rc->code = (rc->code << 8) | (uint8_t)c;
        } else if (rc->range < range_coder_bottom) {
            rc->range <<= 8;
            rc->low <<= 8;
            uint8_t c = 0;
            errno_t r = rc->read(rc, &c);
            if (r != 0) { return r; }
            rc->code = (rc->code << 8) | (uint8_t)c;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    rc_am_update(rc, s);
    *symbol = s;
    return 0;
}

// test

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static inline errno_t write_byte(struct range_coder* rc, uint8_t b) {
    size_t written = fwrite(&b, 1, 1, (FILE*)rc->stream);
    return written == 1 ? 0 : errno;
}

static inline errno_t read_byte(struct range_coder* rc, uint8_t* b) {
    size_t read = fread(b, 1, 1, (FILE*)rc->stream);
    return read == 1 ? 0 : errno;
}

static errno_t test(void) {
    errno_t r = 0;
    uint16_t data[] = {1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 8901, 9012};
    size_t data_size = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
    {
        FILE* out = fopen("encoded.bin", "wb");
        if (!out) {
            perror("Failed to create and open output file");
            return 1;
        }
        static struct range_coder rc_encoder;
        rc_init_encoder(&rc_encoder);
        rc_encoder.stream = out;
        rc_encoder.write = write_byte;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < data_size && r == 0; i++) {
            r = rc_encode(&rc_encoder, data[i]);
        }
        if (r == 0) {
            r = rc_flush(&rc_encoder);
        }
        if (fclose(out) != 0 && r == 0) {
            r = errno;
        }
        if (r != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "i/o error %d %s", r, strerror(r));
            return r;
        }
    }
    { // decode:
        FILE* in = fopen("encoded.bin", "rb");
        if (in == NULL) {
            perror("Failed to open input file");
            return 1;
        }
        static struct range_coder rc_decoder;
        rc_decoder.stream = in;
        rc_decoder.read = read_byte;
        r = rc_init_decoder(&rc_decoder);
        if (r != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "i/o error %d %s", r, strerror(r));
            return r;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < data_size && r == 0; i++) {
            uint16_t symbol = 0;
            r = rc_decode(&rc_decoder, &symbol);
            if (r == 0) {
                if (data[i] != symbol) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "expected %u got %u\n", data[i], symbol);
                    r = EINVAL;
                } else {
                    printf("Decoded symbol: %u\n", symbol);
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(in); // not expected to fail for input file ever
        if (r != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "i/o error %d %s", r, strerror(r));
            return r;
        }
    }
    return r;
}


Why did loop for (uint32_t i = 0; i < range_coder_sym_max; i++) { use type uint32_t for i?  I could see size_t, unsigned, or even int, but where did uint32_t come from?

Just some general random remarks:

The enum as used in your code is non-portable. C historically had the problem that enumeration constants - range_coder_bits are always of the type int, but the enum object has an implementation-defined type which could be of a different size or even unsigned.
So when you write range_coder_sym_max = 1u << range_coder_bits, the expression on the right side of = is of type unsigned int, which is good to avoid signedness problems when shifting. But range_coder_sym_max will be int no matter. Now if this is a system with 16 bit int you'd first get a constant equal to 0x8000 and then try to fit that inside a signed int. After which an implementation-defined conversion from unsigned to signed takes place.
There's no quick fix for maximum portability. It is simply best to avoid enum entirely in combination with any bitwise arithmetic and instead use #define or const variables.
This is generally one sad state of affairs in C. The good news is that upcoming C23 finally solved this language defect, so you'll be able to declare your enum like enum : uint32_t and then both the enum objects and the enumeration constant will be of the specified type. Latest gcc does support -std=c23.

fwrite(&b, 1, 1, (FILE*)rc->stream); The cast could be fishy. Going from void* to any other type doesn't need a cast. But the real question is why you declared the variable void* to begin with and not FILE*, since it should only ever be used in the context where it is passed to/from functions expecting a FILE* type.

errno/errno.h error handling is generally to be avoided, that's a remain from ancient days that we have to suffer because of poorly-designed error handling in some standard lib functions. Similarly, errno_t is be avoided, because it was included in the standard as part of the skunky "bound-checking interface" - which because a fiasco and probably subject to removal from C - that whole mess is a story of its own.
Just roll out your own error type through an enum instead. If you need to call old library functions using errno, then let  your enum be a wrapper around all that.


Coding style (subjective):

It is very common coding style to always write enumeration constants in all capitals, so consider that.
if (r != 0) { return r; } without putting the compound block at a line of its own might be considered less readable.


Thank you. Will fix.
Is there a good way to post fixed version here? I am new to code reviews

@Leo Usually you'd wait a week or so to let everyone chime in - if you still need feedback on the updated code, the best way is probably to ask a new question. Maybe someone has the time to study & review the actual algorithm, which I guess is the most important thing you'd like feedback about?
